# Why is the following not a scalar product?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We have a scalar product:
$$\langle\,,\rangle: R_n[x]\cdot R_n[x]\rightarrow R $$

Now we define:

$$ \langle p,q\rangle_1 = p(1)\cdot q(1)$$

This should not be a scalar product, because it does not satisfy the property that:

$$\langle p,p\rangle_1 = 0 \iff p(1) = 0 $$

However I can't seem to find any example where this would not hold.

I tried:
$$p(x) = x^2-2x+1 $$
$$\langle p,p\rangle_1 = p(1)\cdot p(1) = 0  $$
$$p(1) = 0$$

However in lectures we said that this property should not hold. Can anybody explain why it doesn't hold ?

Comment: What is $R_n[x]$?

Comment: @Soby I see, so I need to look at it before I input the value ?

Comment: @ArcticChar It is a polynomial vector space

Comment: @VLC The definition of ‘scalar product’ i know is that the original vector you put in gives zero input iff the original vector is 0 itself. In this case $p$ Should be identically zero as a polynomial. Unless your professor have a different meaning of this scalar product?

Comment: @Soby Yes this is what the professor certainly meant.

Comment: @Arctic Char The definition given by VLC should have been: "$R_n[X]$ is the $(n+1)$ dimensional vector space of polynomials with degree $\le n$".

Answer (score 3):

You are misinterpreting the definition of a scalar product. Your bilinear form does satisfies the property that you quote, but this is not enough for it to be a scalar product. Namely, if $\langle -,- \rangle_1$ were a scalar product, it would satisfy the stronger property:
$$\langle p, p \rangle_1 = 0\ \Leftrightarrow\ p = 0.$$
And your example is a counter-example to this: you have $\langle p, p \rangle_1 = 0$ but $p \neq 0$ !